# i need a textbox which do not able to press the alphabetic key in javascript

Tags: javascript

i need a textbox which do not able to press the  alphabetic key in Java Script and remove the entered which character.

Comment: have you translated the text from some other language?

Comment: no code, ambiguous question how do you expect an answer??

Comment: Do you mean a numeric-only text input? If so see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

simply add this attribute to your input:

```
onkeydown = "if(/[a-z]/i.test(String.fromCharCode((event||window.event).keyCode))){return false;}"
```